# D3 mouseover transitions gets "stuck"

Tags: javascript, hover, d3.js

Say I want to create regular hover effects for a navigation menu, but instead of CSS I use D3 transitions to "soften up" the effect. This works fine using `mouseover` and `mouseout` for the `.on`-method. The problem, though, is that the transition gets stuck if the mouse leaves the hovered link before the transition is done. How does one avoid that side effect?

For instance, with this code, the bottom border is still displayed in orange even after the mouse has moved elsewhere, if you do it too fast:

```
d3.selectAll("a")
    .on("mouseover", function() { 
       d3.select(this)
      .style("border-bottom-color", "#fff")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .style("border-bottom-color", "#B23600"); })
    .on("mouseout", function() { 
       d3.select(this)
      .style("border-bottom-color", "#fff"); });
```

Comment: I don't know the perfect answer, but I suspect the mouseout is invoked and completed before the duration (1s) of the mouseover is completed. Maybe make a 1100 duration for the mouseout?

Comment: Also, the reading at http://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/ suggests there are differences between d3 versions 2 and 3. Which version are you using?

Comment: Don't have a perfect answer either but: If, like in your example, you're using HTML (rather than SVG), then you can skip the d3 transitions altogether and use css transitions instead. That'll definitely solve the problem you're having, and it'd be more performant. Users of old browsers won't get a transition, but oh wells...

Comment: Hm, I didn't use any transition for the mouseout, but for some reason (I would love an explanation) using a transition for the mouseout as well solved the issue. I'm using version 3 and I set duration to 500 ms for both transitions now.

Comment: I came to this page searching on the same problem, but in reverse - when firing a transition in response to a mouse event, if the pointer stayed still it interrupted the transition. I found a solution by adding the `pointer-events: none` style to an element enclosing the `svg`. More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381375/d3-js-stop-transitions-interrupting-on-mouseover/23718314#23718314

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what is going on is that when you have the `.transition` on only the `mouseover`, 
the transition still has not run its course when you leave before 1000ms have expired. 
So when you leave early, the mouseover transition is still running, 
and there is no transition call on the mouseout event to override this transition. (Apparently not even the `mouseout` event will stop the `.transition` associated with the `mouseover` event.)

However, as you noted, when you do put a `transition` on the mouseout event, 
the problem goes away. And I believe this is because the mouseout `transition` 
takes precedence over the `mouseover` `.transition`, so having a `.transition` on the `mouseout` event puts the `mouseout` event back in control.

You can see it in action here if you comment out the `.transition` on the `mouseout` event.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ldmv6/1/

Also worth reading is Chapter 10 from [Scott Murray's](http://alignedleft.com/) upcoming d3 book: http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449339739/_interactivity.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining!

Comment: Adding transition on mouseout doesn't solve the problem in this example 
http://jsfiddle.net/t466vL71/

Comment: Ok, solved that by removing the dynamicColor approach http://jsfiddle.net/w9q6uh25/